# how to make the first container to be the last in flutter Row widget

Tags: flutter

I can do that using VerticalDirection.down in the Colum widget, but there is no horizontal direction property in the Row widget. Is there a way to put this into practice?

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text("Hello world"),
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),

            Container(
              child: Text("Hello World"),
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("Hello World"),
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```dart
Row(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl
  //...
)
```

Add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` If you want the items to remain on the left side

```dart
Row(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  //...
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add to this line,   `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end`

```
 Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Text("Hello world"),
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
    
                Container(
                  child: Text("Hello World"),
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text("Hello World"),
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.amberAccent,
                ),
              ],
            )
```

Answer (score -1):

put `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` inside row